# how to add dynamic button (value) to custometkinter - CTkSegmentedButton

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.minsize(400, 400)

        button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="add new item", command=self.button_click_event)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
        segemented_button = customtkinter.CTkSegmentedButton(self, values=["Page one", "Page two", "Page three"])
        segemented_button.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
        segemented_button.set("Page one")


    def button_click_event(self):
        self.segemented_button.vlaues.insert(0, 'canada')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I want to add new value to the `CTkSegmentedButton` when `add new item` button is clicked. I try with function `button_click_event()` but it cannot access `values` of `segemented_button`. so how should I modify this code ?

Simply saying I want to add new `value` to `segemented_button` when `add new item` button is clicked.

Comment: The simplest way is to destroy the current window and rebuild it as desired

Comment: If you want to be able to access `self.segemented_button` later, you have to save the widget as `self.segemented_button` in the first place.  Currently, it's just a local variable that vanishes at the end of `__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
segemented_button.configure(values=["Page one", "Page two", "Page three", "Canada"])
segemented_button.set("Canada")
```

Obviously you can save the values to an array

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change local variable `segemented_button` to instance variable `self.segemented_button` inside `__init__()`, otherwise it cannot be accessed elsewhere.

Second you can use `self.segement_button.insert(index, value)` to insert new `value` in given `index`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
import customtkinter
import tkinter


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.minsize(400, 400)

        button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="add new item", command=self.button_click_event)
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

        # changed to instance variable self.segemented_button
        self.segemented_button = customtkinter.CTkSegmentedButton(self, values=["Page one", "Page two", "Page three"])
        self.segemented_button.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
        self.segemented_button.set("Page one")

    def button_click_event(self):
        # get current "values"
        values = self.segemented_button.cget("values")
        # add new value only if the new value is not in "values"
        if "canada" not in values:
            # add new value at the end
            self.segemented_button.insert(len(values), "canada")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```